# Point Symbol ranking like Google Maps based on zoom level and scale in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, symbology, google-maps, scale

I have a challenge to create a style for point layer which show some point of interest in a zoom level then show the other on the next zoom level, considering these

- no overlap between symbol points (which are near in locations) "show only one of them based on given Rank"
- no intersect between labels of these symbol points when they are near to each other

just like google maps do , it hide some of the symbol points then show them in zooming levels based on ranking and also prevent the label intersection  as the following picture

[image]

Comment: You can add display thresholds to entire layers as well as Display Filters to individual features, suggest you explore the help file of ArcPro.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is what I'm looking for, display filter can control display feature based on query.